# fixing Exception in main thread

Tags: java

Everything with my code seems to work correctly, whenever the boolean method returns true. However, when trying to test false, after the user enters 10 numbers I receive the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
at FunArrays.main(FunArrays.java:15
```

What am I missing or overlooking with my code?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FunArrays {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter ten numbers....");

            int [] userArray = new int [9];

        for(int b = 0; b < 10 ; b++){
            userArray [b] = input.nextInt();
        }

            boolean lucky = isLucky(userArray);
                if (lucky){
                        sum(userArray);
    } else
        sumOfEvens(userArray);

}



public static boolean isLucky(int [] numbers){

    for (int i = 0; i <= numbers.length; i++){
        if (numbers[i]== 7 || numbers[i] == 13 || numbers[i] == 18){
            return true;

        }   

    }
    return false;

}



public static void sum(int [] numbers){
    int sum = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x <= numbers.length -1; x++){
        sum += numbers[x];

    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}

public static void sumOfEvens(int [] numbers){
    int evens = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y <= numbers.length -1; y++){
        if (numbers[y] % 2 == 0){
            evens += numbers[y];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(evens);
}

}
```

Comment: usersArray is length 9 (0...8) - but your loop is running from 0 to 9. So when b is 9, you're outside the bounds of your array.

Comment: You are creating array with 9 elements

Comment: Keep in mind arrays are `0-indexed`. This is one of the gotcha's every programmer has and will experience. :)

Comment: when I correct the issues I receive the following error message:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
 at FunArrays.isLucky(FunArrays.java:32)
 at FunArrays.main(FunArrays.java:18)

Now there is an issue with the boolean method, only when it is false.

Answer (score 0):

You are entering 10 numbers but your array has only 9 spots. Change it to

```
int [] userArray = new int [10];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int [] userArray = new int [9];

    for(int b = 0; b < 10 ; b++){
        userArray [b] = input.nextInt();
    }
```

Your array size is 9 (from index 0 to index 8) and your loop increment b from 0 to 9 (10 cases)
In this case b should be less than 9 in your loop.

So you could replace by this code:

```
int maxInput = 9;
int [] userArray = new int [maxInput];

    for(int b = 0; b < maxInput ; b++){
        userArray [b] = input.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: when I correct the issues I receive the following error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10 at FunArrays.isLucky(FunArrays.java:32) at FunArrays.main(FunArrays.java:18) Now there is an issue with the boolean method, only when it is false.

Comment: It seems to be a good exercice :) you need to understand our answers to fix "for" end condition of "isLucky" function. ..

Comment: And same for "sum" and "sumOfEvens" functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a size 10 array, since you are accepting 10 values from the user.

```
int [] userArray = new int [9];
```

Here is a good read on Arrays: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Arrays/arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to store 10 numbers in an array of length 9.

Use `int[] userArray = new int[10];`